# ReactJS - read json value, first level values are readable but, second level showing error

Tags: reactjs

This is code

```
const UserItem = (user, index) => (
  <div key={index} className="accordion__item js-accordion-item">
    <div className="accordion-header js-accordion-header">{(index+1)} . {user.invoiceId}
              </div>
    <div className="accordion-body js-accordion-body">
      <div className="accordion-body__contents">
        {user.sender.city}
               <button href="#" onClick={handleClick} id={user.invoiceId}>
                Click me
               </button>      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @lgor please check

Comment: You obviously missing the component which uses `city` property. I don't see anywhere in your code the ussage of .city .

Comment: so the error is from somewhere else please update with the line where you getting error

Comment: How many items your array has? Maybe some of them don't have 'sender' property?

Comment: Both city and name has error.

Comment: seems working https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-crhz2q , guess problem in few items  don't have sender

Answer (score 0):

You probably used your component `UserItem` like this in your code

```
{
   users.map((user, index) => <UserItem user={user} index={index} />)
}
```

In this case you must declare your component like this

```
const UserItem = ({user, index}) => ( ... );
```

instead of

```
const UserItem = (user, index) => ( ... );
```

Finally you should set the key property on `UserItem`, not on the div inside `UserItem` so basically you shoud write

```
{
   users.map((user, index) => <UserItem user={user} index={index} key={index} />)
}
```

or event better with a unique id

```
{
   users.map((user, index) => <UserItem user={user} index={index} key={user.invoiceId}/>)
}
```

Comment: Why not `UserItem = (props) => (...)`

Comment: yes it's ok with props but you can use `es6 object destructuring` to get the props you are interested in

Comment: I meant, you suggested that he accepted the parameters like `(user , index)` , but I say that it's probably not the case, which means that this won't solve his problem . Defienetly need more info to determine .